# SpringBoot CrudRepository not being found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to SpringBoot and just doing a learning project with it. I got the HelloWorld done and am moving onto database. I added a Repository class based on examples, and am getting the below. Which based on searching alot of people get.  The problem is that the solutions I've seen don't fix me.  My repository IS in a sub-package of the main class. I have a 'data' and 'controller' subpackage at the moment.  I tried a bunch of bits of advice, and none seem to fix me.  Relevant source below.

```
Description:


Field assets in mypkg.microsvc.controller.AssetController required a bean of type 'mypkg.microsvc.data.AssetRepository' that could not be found.


The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'mypkg.microsvc.data.AssetRepository' in your configuration.
```

Entity (notice I DO have an @Entity annotation)

```
package mypkg.microsvc.data;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
[...]
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSET_T", schema = "K702PRDR")
public class Asset implements java.io.Serializable  { 
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4631085917731566134L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ASSET_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String assetId;
[...]
```

Repository interface (I've tried with and without the annotation, extending CrudRepository and JpaRepository)

```
package mypkg.microsvc.data;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
[...]

@Repository
public interface AssetRepository extends JpaRepository<Asset, String> {
  public List<Asset> findAll();
}
```

Application object (I've tried many different annotations to try to get it to scan and see my repository as you can see...this isn't even all the iterations.  As I understand it, given that my app object is 'above' the repository in package hierarchy, I should ONLY need the @SpringBootApplication annotation.  But I wanted to show that I've tried all these things and I get the same outcome.)

```
package mypkg.microsvc;
[...]
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
    "mypkg.microsvc", 
    "mypkg.microsvc.controller", 
    "mypkg.microsvc.data"})
//@EnableJpaRepositories("mypkg.microsvc.data")
//@EntityScan("mypkg.microsvc.data")
@ComponentScan(basePackages={
    "mypkg.microsvc", 
    "mypkg.microsvc.controller", 
    "mypkg.microsvc.data"})
public class MicroApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(MicroApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

And here's my controller.  Again, i've gone through a few iterations

```
 package mypkg.microsvc.controller;

 [...]
 import mypkg.microsvc.data.Asset;
 import mypkg.microsvc.data.AssetRepository;

 @RestController
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 public class AssetController {
   @Autowired
   AssetRepository assets;

   @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public @ResponseBody List<Asset> list() {
     return assets.findAll();
   }
}
```

I'm under the impression that this is all it should take.  Where am i screwing this up?

Update (adding the trace when i turn the trace on):

```
2021-04-08 15:36:41.593 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The Apache Tomcat Native library could not be found using names [tcnative-1, libtcnative-1] on the java.library.path [C:\DevApps\IBM\WebSphere\AppServerV9\java\8.0\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\DevApps\IBM\WebSphere\AppServerV9\java\8.0\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\DevApps\IBM\WebSphere\AppServerV9\java\8.0\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_252\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin\NOTES\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin\NOTES\DATA\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\RationalSDLC\common;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient\cteapis;C:\Program Files (x86)\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\bmulholl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]. The errors reported were [C:\views\CATS_Development\CATS_SW\SpringBootMicroTest\bin\tcnative-1.dll (The specified module could not be found. ), C:\views\CATS_Development\CATS_SW\SpringBootMicroTest\bin\libtcnative-1.dll (The specified module could not be found. ), tcnative-1 (Not found in java.library.path), libtcnative-1 (Not found in java.library.path)]

org.apache.tomcat.jni.LibraryNotFoundError: C:\views\CATS_Development\CATS_SW\SpringBootMicroTest\bin\tcnative-1.dll (The specified module could not be found. ), C:\views\CATS_Development\CATS_SW\SpringBootMicroTest\bin\libtcnative-1.dll (The specified module could not be found. ), tcnative-1 (Not found in java.library.path), libtcnative-1 (Not found in java.library.path)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getDefaultLifecycleListeners(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:173) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.<init>(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:120) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.tomcatServletWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration.java:76) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$222/000000001247BD90.getObject(Unknown Source) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) [spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:216) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at gov.usdoj.afms.microsvc.MicroApplication.main(MicroApplication.java:19) [bin/:na]

2021-04-08 15:36:42.064 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat   : Class not found so assuming code is running on a pre-Java 9 JVM

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method) ~[na:2.9 (04-02-2020)]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:337) ~[na:2.9 (04-02-2020)]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.<clinit>(Jre9Compat.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.<clinit>(JreCompat.java:70) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.<clinit>(Tomcat.java:1303) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:185) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at gov.usdoj.afms.microsvc.MicroApplication.main(MicroApplication.java:19) [bin/:na]

2021-04-08 15:36:42.067 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre16Compat  : Class not found so assuming code is running on a pre-Java 16 JVM

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.net.UnixDomainSocketAddress
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method) ~[na:2.9 (04-02-2020)]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:337) ~[na:2.9 (04-02-2020)]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre16Compat.<clinit>(Jre16Compat.java:47) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.<clinit>(JreCompat.java:70) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.<clinit>(Tomcat.java:1303) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:185) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at gov.usdoj.afms.microsvc.MicroApplication.main(MicroApplication.java:19) [bin/:na]

2021-04-08 15:36:42.841 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol port=8080)
2021-04-08 15:36:42.862 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol bindOnInit=false)
2021-04-08 15:36:42.863 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Set [bindOnInit] to [false]
2021-04-08 15:36:42.864 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint bindOnInit=false)
2021-04-08 15:36:42.867 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol maxPostSize=2097152)
2021-04-08 15:36:42.868 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Set [maxPostSize] to [2097152]
2021-04-08 15:36:42.869 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint maxPostSize=2097152)
2021-04-08 15:36:42.924 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : Add child StandardHost[localhost] StandardEngine[Tomcat]
2021-04-08 15:36:42.995 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : Add child TomcatEmbeddedContext[] StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.019 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol parseBodyMethods=POST)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.020 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Set [parseBodyMethods] to [POST]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.020 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint parseBodyMethods=POST)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.021  INFO 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.023  INFO 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.026 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Starting ROOT
2021-04-08 15:36:43.055 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Configuring default Resources
2021-04-08 15:36:43.288 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Processing standard container startup
2021-04-08 15:36:43.289 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader  : Starting this Loader
2021-04-08 15:36:43.298 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesRmiTargets=false)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.299 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesStopThreads=false)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.300 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesStopTimerThreads=false)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.300 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesHttpClientKeepAliveThread=true)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.301 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches=false)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.301 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches=false)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.302 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils  : IntrospectionUtils: setProperty(class org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreadLocals=false)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.346 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : No SingleSignOn Valve is present
2021-04-08 15:36:43.347 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : No manager found. Checking if cluster manager should be used. Cluster configured: [false], Application distributable: [false]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.353 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Configured a manager of class [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.361  INFO 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-08 15:36:43.448 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : Add child StandardWrapper[dispatcherServlet] StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.483 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Configuring application event listeners
2021-04-08 15:36:43.484 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Sending application start events
2021-04-08 15:36:43.487 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager     : Start: Loading persisted sessions
2021-04-08 15:36:43.488 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager     : Loading persisted sessions from [SESSIONS.ser]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.488 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager     : No persisted data file found
2021-04-08 15:36:43.489 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Starting filters
2021-04-08 15:36:43.489 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Starting filter 'requestContextFilter'
2021-04-08 15:36:43.503 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Starting filter 'Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter'
2021-04-08 15:36:43.504 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Starting filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
2021-04-08 15:36:43.504 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Starting filter 'formContentFilter'
2021-04-08 15:36:43.505 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Starting completed
2021-04-08 15:36:43.512 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper        : Registered host [localhost]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.513 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Register Wrapper [dispatcherServlet] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.513 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Register Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.514 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Register host [localhost] at domain [null] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.622  INFO 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.624 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Unregister host [localhost] at domain [null] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.625 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Unregister Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.626 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Unregister Wrapper [dispatcherServlet] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.627 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Stopping filters
2021-04-08 15:36:43.627 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Stopping filter 'requestContextFilter'
2021-04-08 15:36:43.628 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.core.ApplicationFilterConfig       : JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter] and name [requestContextFilter]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.628 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Stopping filter 'Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter'
2021-04-08 15:36:43.628 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.core.ApplicationFilterConfig       : JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter] and name [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.629 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Stopping filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
2021-04-08 15:36:43.630 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.core.ApplicationFilterConfig       : JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter] and name [characterEncodingFilter]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.631 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Stopping filter 'formContentFilter'
2021-04-08 15:36:43.631 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.core.ApplicationFilterConfig       : JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter] and name [formContentFilter]
2021-04-08 15:36:43.631 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager     : Stopping
2021-04-08 15:36:43.633 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager     : Unloading persisted sessions
2021-04-08 15:36:43.633 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager     : No persisted sessions to unload
2021-04-08 15:36:43.634 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Sending application stop events
2021-04-08 15:36:43.634 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Processing standard container shutdown
2021-04-08 15:36:43.634 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader  : Stopping this Loader
2021-04-08 15:36:43.635 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : getResourceAsStream(org/apache/catalina/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention.class)
2021-04-08 15:36:43.635 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   Delegating to parent classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3f966a4f
2021-04-08 15:36:43.636 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   --> Returning stream from parent
2021-04-08 15:36:43.651 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : resetContext Tomcat:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
2021-04-08 15:36:43.659 DEBUG 17920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Stopping complete
15:36:43.830 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field assetSuppository in gov.usdoj.afms.microsvc.service.AssetService required a bean of type 'gov.usdoj.afms.microsvc.repository.AssetRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'gov.usdoj.afms.microsvc.repository.AssetRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Leave only `@SpringBootApplication` remove all the other clutter from your application class. Remove `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from your controller it doesn't make sense nor is needed.

Comment: @M.Deinum - That's where I started.  The clutter was various things I saw people do to fix similar errors in other threads.  I just went and wiped all of that out so that only SpringBootApplication remains.  Same exact error.

Comment: Run your application with --debug to see the full stack trace (or if you have that put it in the question). The `@Repository` on the interface will do nothing. If the package structure is as you state it is, it should work, if it isn't the package structure is different or there is a different cause for the JPA Repositry not being available like no datasource configured or available, JPA config missing etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I put --debug in the program args, and saw that string passed into the run method.  Yet the output didn't change.  When I add -Ddebug to the jvm parms, I get a ton of logging debug, when I add debug: true to application.yml I get a bunch of tomcat extra.  But I'm not seeing the spring extra debug info.  I'm wondering if it's relevant to mention i constructed this project without Maven.  My job is on a govt machine and we're trying to convince them to let us use Maven, but they're very reluctant.  So I DLed the jars manually from Maven.  I don't think i missed anything, but...maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused because I'm very sure that I did this before and it didn't work, but adding @EnableJpaRepositories to the application class WITHOUT any package specifications while removing the other extraneous annotations worked for me. I also added an AssetService between the repository and controller, though that didn't work when i did just that, so it wasn't really the solution..

But this just seems to have gotten me to the NEXT error -

```
Field assetRepository in gov.usdoj.afms.microsvc.service.AssetService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

So I'm still not working yet, but this specific issue went away.

Comment: Adding that annotation shouldn't be necessary as that should be detected by Spring Boot. Judging from what you are saying that you cannot use maven or grade you are basically in a pickle because you need either to create a proper runnable jar/war file for Spring Boot. The plugin does additional work.

Answer (score -1):

To keep the spring-boot application simple, The packing structure should be followed so that the spring-boot does its thing to scan the packages and creates the bean for Auto wiring.

In your case, the package structure should be as follows

1. MicroApplication.java should be in package mypkg.microsvc
2. AssetController.java should be in package mypkg.microsvc.controller
3. AssetRepository.java should be in package mypkg.microsvc.repository
4. Asset.java should be in package mypkg.microsvc.entity

This packing structure allows the Spring-boot application to scan all the packages automatically. This way you don't have to add all the extra boiler plate code in the main app class. The moto of the Spring-boot application is to reduce boiler plate code as much as possible

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MicroApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(MicroApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to package by type, as long as the spring boot application can detect them in packages it is ok. How to package has been food for debates for over years already.

Comment: @Raj-thugu - I tried renaming and organizing my packages as you suggested (though my understanding was consistent with M.Deinum that this would not matter).  I got the same error.  Other ideas?